# Virtualising Intel Graphics 620

Tags: virtual-machine, intel-graphics, games

Situation: Buying a new laptop. But newer models of laptop usually comes with integrated graphics instead of dedicated ones.

Problem: I want to run Linux as my base OS and use a VM to play games (i.e. VMware Workstation Player) as I do not like the idea of dual booting.

Question: Has anyone virtualised Intel Graphics 620 before? If so, how is the performance like?

Additional Information: I play League of Legends, a graphically demanding game. I am also open to using options such as using KVM to virtualise my Intel Grphics using KVMGT, but linking to tutorials will be helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have a laptop that has an Intel HD Graphics 620 installed. I play League of Legends through PlayOnLinux (a sort of VM for windows applications) and it doesnt run at constant 30-40 fps. However, fps do not change when changing video graphics as of yet.

Comment: *does run at constrant

Comment: You can edit your own post, and in this case you should, to add a bit more information and clean what you wanted to say.

Comment: Thanks! But do note that PlayOnLinux actually runs at near-native speeds. Your LoL is an NA/EU version. My SEA version is not able to run on POL and that's why I need VMware. VMware, on the other hand relies on paravirtualisation, which is supposedly slower than speeds POL is capable of. But I do appreciate the information :)